# How to get rid off java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have went through many links and similar questions related to  **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** but none of the solutions resolved my problem. So here is my question,
I have a web application where user uploads a Excel file that has records around 2500 my application reads contents of this file and inserts them into Database.
but after inserting 700 records I am getting exception as **throwable object caught= java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Same code works if file contains 500 or less than 500 records. following is my JAVA_OPTS & CATALINA_OPTS variable in catalina.bat file

```
    JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
    CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

can anyone please tell me what can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: chek out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443937/java-heap-memory-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443937/java-heap-memory-error)

Comment: What are you using to read the spreadsheet?

Comment: Definetly you have to rethink about performed operations. Don't try to read all ~2500 records in a one step. Make this process iterative. I mean, read portion of data, insert it into your db. Repeat this process until you reach the end.

Comment: @Bob Flannigon : JExcelApi  is used for reading Excel file

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are loading the entire file in memory.
Can you try to convert your Excel file to plain-text CSV and then read it line by line by using the Java class `Scanner`?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("yourCsvFile.csv");

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    //process your line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone please tell me what can be done to resolve this issue?

It sounds to me like you have a memory leak (i.e. a bug) in your application.  Without seeing your code, we can't tell you where it is.  However the answers to these questions explain how to find memory leaks in Java programs:

- [General strategy to resolve Java memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473510/general-strategy-to-resolve-java-memory-leak)
- [How to find a Java Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak)

---

I should point out that you have specified two different values for the heap size in the JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS variables.  Only one of this is going to take effect, but which one depends on the details of the script that is used to start Tomcat.

However, a properly written application shouldn't run out of memory while uploading data from a spreadsheet.  A heap size of 512Mb should be plenty.

Comment: thanks for your answer,can you tell me what changes should I make in order to make heap size 512Mb? because my tomcat manager always shows Max memory: 247.50 MB for JVM

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Hibernate to insert the records. Hibernate maintains a *session cache* of all saved objects and postpones any actual inserts until transaction commit. You must *flush* the session cache every 100 records or so. It is also advised to *disable the second-level cache* while doing a massive insert.

There are several other issues related to batch inserts with Hibernate and [the official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) is mandatory reading for anyone implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you close you File stream?If you didn't close you file stream,the heap size would be very bigger!Then it would throw a OutOfMemoryError exception.So,check that if you close the file stream!